# Why is JSHint throwing a "possible strict violation" on this line

Tags: javascript

Trying to validate some Javascript in JsHint, and I get the following:

Possible strict violation:

```
return ($.event.dispatch || $.event.handle).apply(this, args);
```

Any ideas why it's throwing that error?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 14):

JSHint isn't sure whether the function that code is in will be called with an actual `this`.

To tell JSHint how the function will be called and suppress this warning, add `/*jshint validthis: true */` to the top of the function.

Comment: Perfect, didn't know you could do that, thanks!

Comment: awesome. doesn't have to be at the top of the function apparently, in my unit test I had to test the context the function was being called in, I added the jshint comment just above where I used `this` (for contextual reference) and it still worked for me.

Comment: wondering if you should necromance this answer in the question this is marked a duplicate of? (because I didn't see it there)