# Using this in event handler in strict javascript?

Tags: javascript, this, jshint, strict

Suppose you have a routine like the following to wire up click event handlers

```
getElements(".board>div").forEach(function(elem){
  elem.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
});
```

And then in the handler, you need to work with the sender (i.e. this)

```
function handleClick(){      
  if(this.innerText.toLowerCase() !== "x"){ 
    ...
```

How do you use `this` in this scenario without a jshint violation/warning?

Comment: why not add just one handler to the .board?

Comment: Why does JSHint think `this` is bad?

Comment: It's not jshint per se that says "this" is bad. It's just that jshint advises you to `"use strict"` and in strict mode `this` outside of method calls is always bound to `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of `this` is valid. To suppress the `this` errors in your event handler add `/*jshint validthis: true */` to the top of the function.

Found that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16553290/552067

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just bind the function with the object?

```
getElements(".board>div").forEach(function(elem){
  elem.addEventListener("click", handleClick.bind(elem));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use one eventhandler

especially if you have many elements inside your board.

adding multiple eventlisteners slows down the browser.

js

```
function h(e){
 alert(e.target.textContent)
}
document.getElementsByClassName('board')[0].onclick=h
```

or

```
document.querySelector('.board').addEventListener('click',h,false)
```

html

```
<div class="board"><div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div></div>
```

example

http://jsfiddle.net/3csJ2/

in your case...

```
function h(e){
 e.target.innerText==1||(alert('this is not 1')/*,...*/) 
}
```

example 2

http://jsfiddle.net/3csJ2/1/

inside the handler function (h) `this` is the 'board'.