# JS: this reference does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, argument-passing

I want to encapsulate my Javascript code for certain objects in structures as indicated below. However, I ran into trouble with the semantics of `this`.

While `this` during `tiles.init()` refers to the `tiles` object, in the event handlers it refers to the event, i.e. I cannot use `this` to call other methods from my object.

Is there any way to pass the object to the event handlers, such that I do not have to use the global variable to call my own sub-routines **and still retain** `this` from the callback context?

I put up a [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/7bjcp5rL/7/). This is the working JS part:

```
myData = {
    'color': "red",
    'makeRed': function(){
        // don't want reference to global here!
        $(this).css("color",myData.color);
    },
    'reset': function(){
        $(this).css("color","");
    },
    'init': function(){
        $("#click").hover(this.makeRed,this.reset);
    }
};

myData.init();
```

I found several solutions like [this](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/pass-arguments-to-event-handler) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979337/how-can-i-pass-arguments-to-event-handlers-in-jquery) idea to pass additional arguments. The question has been marked a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19711385/using-this-in-event-handler-in-strict-javascript), but using `.bind()` wastes the `this` required for the jQuery inside the callback.

Any idea how to get both `tiles` and `this` of the event context to the handler function without using globals?

Comment: `.hover(this.hoverIn.bind(this), this.hoverOut.bind(this))`

Comment: I actually missed that answer, but it does not solve the full issue. It leads to the suggestion made by elclanrs. This brings tiles as this, but drops the event, i.e. jQuery $(this) does not work anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a closure variable in the `init` method

```
'init': function () {
    var self = this;
    $("#tiles div.tile").hover(function () {
        self.hoverIn(this);
    }, function () {
        self.hoverOut(this);
    });
}
```

---

Your construct is not working because `this` inside the hover callbacks does not refer to the `tiles` object

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. this.hoverIn works fine in init! Making the callbacks accept an argument set to self, makes $(this) fail inside the callbacks.

Comment: Okay, made it. The trick is about function(){self.hoverIn(self,$(this))} to pass both parameters to the handler. I tried something similar before I asked the question, but must have done something wrong. Thanks for the hint - the bind() variant does not work for me.